# How do I make a POST call in Rails without automatically going to the default create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, post, http-post

I have been having a problem with Rails lately where all the example code I've seen so far for sending data via POST is always routed to this default root URL which automatically calls a #create method in the controller. I wanted to know how do I go about making a form that sends data via POST but to a different method that I define?

In this particular example, I have a widget that needs to allow for file uploads. However, this upload could result in either a creation or a replace, but in either case it is only specific to this widget on the page. There are other widgets also capable of creating things and I need to keep the logic for them separated instead of just routing them all through some create method. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you make custom POST routes.

In routes,

```rb
resources :whatevers do
  member do
    post 'customizedpost'
  end
end
```

In your whatever controller

```
def customizedpost
  # all the post stuff
end
```

And in your form for example

```
= form_for @whatever, url: customizedpost_whatever_path, html: { method: :post } do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for posting the form with HAML since I'm using that instead of ERB.By the way, in the routing where you have the resource block, is there a way to do this without using a resource? So far I've been doing all my routing through the match one-liners since there is no actual use of ActiveRecord for models in this rails app and all the other stuff has been using GET to pass data.

Comment: The location of `resources :whatevers blah` shouldn't matter, so long as you don't overwrite the routes in the the latter part of routes.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit that because I hit enter when I meant to just add a newline, not to actually send the comment post yet.

Comment: Sure, one liner would look something like this. match `'whatevers/customizedpost' => 'whatevers#customizedpost', via: :post`

I would also check out [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thank you! You have no clue how much Googling I have done and not come across a single example with that routing line with the "via :post" part added on. You have no clue how much you have just helped me.